# Simple function that retrieves data from an API is not returning the data

Tags: reactjs

I have this React component that used to return an HTML element like this:

```
const PartsList = () => {

    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const result = await axios(
                'https://localhost:44376/api/parts',
            );
            setData(result.data);
        };
        fetchData();
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            {data.map((item, index) => (
                <label key={index} className="inline">
                    <Field key={index} type="checkbox" name="machineParts" value={item.id} />
                    {item.name}
                </label>
            ))}
        </>

    );
}
export default PartsList;
```

Now, I want it to return only an array of JSON, no HTML.

So I tried modifying the component so that it looks like this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const [data, setData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = async () => {
    const result = await axios(
      'https://localhost:44376/api/machines',
    );
    setData(result.data);
    console.log("data as seen in function: ", JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
  };
  fetchData();
}, []);

return data;
```

When I write it out to the console in this function, I see all the needed data.

But when I write it out to the console in the main App.js, I just see undefined.

What could I be doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: useEffect is a lifecycle function. If it's not in a component it won't do anything.

Comment: @BarryMichaelDoyle So I can safely remove that?  I was trying to use the new React Hooks thanks

Comment: It's important to know how hooks work, there are very good places to use them. This case is not. Hooks have specific purposes. Eg. the useEffect is for running code when the component mounts and unmounts, and when certain props change (you set this in the hook dependencies). Read up more about it. Your use case here didn't require hooks. And a hook "hooks" to a component, they don't work standalone, let what you attemted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Originally you wanted a component because it had to render HTML.

Now what you actually need is to move everything out to a function.

So you can do this in your main `App.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const fetchData = async () => {
  const result = await axios(
    'https://localhost:44376/api/machines',
  );
  return JSON.stringify(result, null, 2);
};

const App = () => {
  const result = await fetchData()
  console.log(result)

  return <div>Main App<div>
}

export default App
```

This is how you make a function to return data that you can call to see the console result in your main App component.

This obviously just demonstrates the concept, you can take it further by moving that function out to its own file that you can import into your `App.js` folder.

Comment: Oh Ok, so I think the only thing I was doing wrong was using the 'useEffect' hook?

Comment: Hi, so I tried your method, but it doesn't seem to be returning my data in the correct format.  According to my console, it's returning a 'promise' which causes errors like 'TypeError: data.map is not a function' later in the app which I'm guessing is because it's returning a promise and not a true JSON array like what it needs.